# Как сгруппировать данные по определенной колонке и вывести их в необходимом порядке?

Tags: sql, bigquery

У меня есть таблица: 
Вот пример данных:

```
carrier                      id                                        email                 date
indosat ooredoo 0001cec9-87cf-4fb4-a42c-3e194dc0b02c    38c18b74f7c5435ddeeabbcb57532a28    2020-02-08
indosat ooredoo 00590797-3165-435f-b55d-77af1b16fc21    51389e6392e540b3c7c73f3e1bb63d44    2020-02-19
3               006e0dfa-5607-4417-9688-a5c41d7645a9    f031692d3c1ff7d1ee82cf18643fdd4e    2020-03-04
telkomsel       00723bb0-3846-4162-af48-24d282abdf95    1d01620025f482958b07549a182a0b56    2020-02-23
telkomsel       007247db-a51a-409a-bf4c-e030e9b70b1f    f7412b4854512780db1fba9a2960c91f    2020-02-08
telkomsel       0091a7c4-392a-4af5-aabe-80e8a1172d3c    cef5e37d5b09a4dca41552eab6a5ee59    2020-02-24
```

В этой таблице:

- `caried` - название мобильного оператора
- `id` - id мобильного устройства
- `email` - е-мейл на мобильном устройстве
- `время`, когда было обнаружено действие

Я хочу сгруппировать данные по `email`, вывести количество раз когда пользователь менял и `id` и `carrier` и вывести только пользователей, в которых это было больше, чем 2 раза. Кроме того, все данные внутри одного `email` должны быть упорядочены по `date`
Вот пример исходящей таблицы:

```
email                               num id                                      carrier     date
38c18b74f7c5435ddeeabbcb57532a28    2   0001cec9-87cf-4fb4-a42c-3e194dc0b02c    telkomsel   2020-02-07
                                        0091a7c4-392a-4af5-aabe-80e8a1172d3c    3           2020-03-04
51389e6392e540b3c7c73f3e1bb63d44    3   1653dc67d73cb2f8316203f9240dec67        3           2020-03-07
                                        0178e5f3acbdf750b26324d4eaef0153        toro        2020-02-17
                                        ae8ecd6ae309fc51278ed378f86a36b5        indosat     2020-02-22
```

Этот запрос я буду выполнять в `BigQuery`
Как можно решить задачу? 
Спасибо

Comment: Используйте подзапрос для получения email, у которых более 2 смен (кстати, смена А-Б-А-Б хронологически - это сколько смен?). Используйте полученный подзапрос для отбора только нужных записей.

Answer (score 0):

готовите запрос с данными

SELECT email, count(distinct id), count(distinct carrier) from table group by email having count(distinct id) > 2 or count(distinct carrier) > 2

далее подключаете к основной таблице по email и сортируете и выводите как хотите